# Cannot locate perl module even if cpanm claims it is up to date

Tags: perl

I tried to use the `File::Slurp` module:

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $text = read_file( 'test.txt' ) ;
```

but when I run this I get error:

```
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/fcihh/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/fcihh/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/fcihh/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/fcihh/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./p.perl line 5.
```

Running `cpanm File::Slurp` gives:

```
File::Slurp is up to date. (9999.19)
```

Comment: Try running this command: `perldoc -l File::Slurp` and see what it gives you. That's the location of where `File::Slurp` is stored. If `perldoc` turns up nothing, try using `cpan` instead of `cpanm` which would be `cpan install File::Slurp`. Or run `cpan` in interactive mode.

Comment: Thanks! `cpan install File::Slurp` worked.. `perldoc -l File::Slurp` gave `No documentation found for "File::Slurp".`

Comment: That means that `cpan`'s and `perldoc`'s shebang are for the same `perl` the script uses, and `cpanm`'s shebang is for the other Perl.

Comment: @ikegami How do check which shebang of cpanm is using?

Comment: "Shebang" refers to the characters "#!" at the very beginning of a file. The remainder of the line is the path to an executable. `which cpanm` will probably give the path to `cpanm`. Don't go editing it! If you want `cpanm` for the sam `perl` as your script, install it using that `perl` and then make sure your PATH is ordered as you want it.

Comment: Or use [PerlBrew](http://perlbrew.pl) for running multiple Perls on the same machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are probably two `perl` involved. Execute the following, using the same `perl` as you're using to execute the script (specify the path if necessary):

```
perl -e'use CPAN; install "File::Slurp"'
```

---

You've since mentioned that your `cpan` (unlike your `cpanm`) is configured to use the same `perl` as you're using to execute your script, so you can simply use

```
cpan File::Slurp
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already resolved the issue by using `cpan` instead of `cpanm` according to the comment of @DawidW

Comment: `cpan` could just as easily have used the wrong `perl` as `cpanm`. Basically, I showed how to get `cpan` with the correct `perl`. You just got lucky that you didn't need to. You have a wonky system.