# File::Read perl Module installation Error. asking for File::Slurp which already installed

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to run perl script on different machine but i got the Error saying..

> Can't locate File/Read.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at fetch_GIS_remote_cra.pl line 15. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at fetch_GIS_remote_cra.pl line 15

what i am understand from this. i should install File:Read module but when I install it fails ask for supporting dependency module called File:Slurp is already installed. please guide how to solve this problem.

I am using Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit.

Thanks

```
cpan[1]> install File::Read 
    Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
      Database was generated on Sun, 02 Nov 2014 15:17:02 GMT
    Running install for module 'File::Read'
    Running make for S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz
    Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz ok
    Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
DEL(1/1): /root/.cpan/build/Math-BigInt-1.9993-Ir7GHd 

  CPAN.pm: Going to build S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz

Checking prerequisites...
  build_requires:
    !  File::Slurp is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'File-Read' version '0.0801'
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz      ----
    File::Slurp [build_requires]
Running Build test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running Build install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'File::Slurp'
Running make for U/UR/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/U/UR/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build U/UR/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for File::Slurp
Writing MYMETA.yml
cp lib/File/Slurp.pm blib/lib/File/Slurp.pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::Slurp.3pm
  URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/append_null.t ....... ok   
t/binmode.t ........... ok   
t/chomp.t ............. ok   
t/data_list.t ......... ok   
t/data_scalar.t ....... ok   
t/edit_file.t ......... ok   
t/error.t ............. ok     
t/error_mode.t ........ ok   
t/file_object.t ....... ok   
t/handle.t ............ ok   
t/inode.t ............. ok   
t/large.t ............. ok       
t/newline.t ........... ok   
t/no_clobber.t ........ ok   
t/original.t .......... ok   
t/paragraph.t ......... ok     
t/perms.t ............. ok   
t/pod.t ............... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
t/pod_coverage.t ...... skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/prepend_file.t ...... ok   
t/pseudo.t ............ ok   
t/read_dir.t .......... ok   
t/signal.t ............ ok   
t/slurp.t ............. ok   
t/stdin.t ............. ok   
t/stringify.t ......... ok   
t/tainted.t ........... ok   
t/write_file_win32.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=28, Tests=296,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr  0.02 sys +  1.46 cusr  0.20 csys =  1.81 CPU)
Result: PASS
  URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Appending installation info to /root/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int/perllocal.pod
  URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
Running Build for S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq

  CPAN.pm: Going to build S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'File::Slurp => 0' for 'SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz' already built but the result looks suspicious. Skipping another build attempt, to prevent looping endlessly.
Building File-Read
  SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz
  ./Build -- OK
Running Build test
t/00-load.t ....... 1/1 
#   Failed test 'use File::Read;'
#   at t/00-load.t line 6.
#     Tried to use 'File::Read'.
#     Error:  Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/arch /root/.cpan/build /root/.cpan/build/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib/File/Read.pm line 4.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib/File/Read.pm line 4.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $File::Read::VERSION in concatenation (.) or string at t/00-load.t line 9.
# Testing File::Read , Perl 5.014002, /usr/bin/perl
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/00-load.t ....... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 
t/distchk.t ....... skipped: Test::Distribution required for checking distribution
t/file-read.t ..... 1/41 
#   Failed test 'use File::Read;'
#   at t/file-read.t line 122.
#     Tried to use 'File::Read'.
#     Error:  Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/arch /root/.cpan/build /root/.cpan/build/ /root/.cpan/build/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib/File/Read.pm line 4.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/File-Read-0.0801-jRboRq/blib/lib/File/Read.pm line 4.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 10) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 10) line 2.

#   Failed test 'File::Read->can(...)'
#   at t/file-read.t line 125.
#     File::Read->can('read_file') failed
#     File::Read->can('read_files') failed

#   Failed test 'main->can(...)'
#   at t/file-read.t line 128.
#     main->can('read_file') failed
#     main->can('read_files') failed

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with no argument'
#   at t/file-read.t line 133.
#                   'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 132.
# '
#     doesn't match '/^error: This function needs at least one path/'

#   Failed test 'calling read_files() with no argument'
#   at t/file-read.t line 137.
#                   'Undefined subroutine &main::read_files called at t/file-read.t line 136.
# '
#     doesn't match '/^error: This function needs at least one path/'

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with a file that does not exist'
#   at t/file-read.t line 141.
#                   'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 140.
# '
#     doesn't match '/^error: read_file 'not/such/file' - /'

#   Failed test 'calling read_files() with invalid value for option 'err_mode''
#   at t/file-read.t line 145.
#                   'Undefined subroutine &main::read_files called at t/file-read.t line 144.
# '
#     doesn't match '/^error: Bad value 'pwadak' for option 'err_mode'/'

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/empty''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/space''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: ' '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/newline''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/pi''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '3.14159265358979
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/hello''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'Hello'

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/world''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'world
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/hello','t/samples/space','t/samples/world''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'Hello world
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/jerkcity2630''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'DEUCE: PLEASE DO THESE STEPS IN THE FOLLOWING ORDERS:
# DEUCE: 1. SHUT UP
# DEUCE: 2. GET THE FUCK OUT
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/config''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '# something that looks like a configuration file
# # with a few comments, and some empty lines
# 
# # enable debug
# debug = 1
# 
# # be verbose
# verbose = 1
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'skip_comments' => 1},'t/samples/config''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '
# debug = 1
# 
# verbose = 1
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'skip_blanks' => 1},'t/samples/config''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '# something that looks like a configuration file
# # with a few comments, and some empty lines
# # enable debug
# debug = 1
# # be verbose
# verbose = 1
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'skip_blanks' => 1,'skip_comments' => 1},'t/samples/config''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'debug = 1
# verbose = 1
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'to_ascii' => 1},'t/samples/latin1''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'agrave:  aelig:  eacute:  szlig:  eth:   thorn:   mu:
# pound:   laquo:  raquo:   sect:   para:  middot:
# '

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'as_root' => 1},'t/samples/hello''
#   at t/file-read.t line 160.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 159.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking result'
#   at t/file-read.t line 161.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'ROOT:Hello'

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: 't/samples/empty','t/samples/newline','t/samples/space''
#   at t/file-read.t line 170.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 169.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking results: number of elements'
#   at t/file-read.t line 171.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '3'

#   Failed test 'checking results: deep compare'
#   at t/file-read.t line 172.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = Does not exist
#     $expected->[0] = ''

#   Failed test 'calling read_file() with args: {'aggregate' => 0},'t/samples/jerkcity2630''
#   at t/file-read.t line 170.
#          got: 'Undefined subroutine &main::read_file called at t/file-read.t line 169.
# '
#     expected: ''

#   Failed test 'checking results: number of elements'
#   at t/file-read.t line 171.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '3'

#   Failed test 'checking results: deep compare'
#   at t/file-read.t line 172.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = Does not exist
#     $expected->[0] = 'DEUCE: PLEASE DO THESE STEPS IN THE FOLLOWING ORDERS:
#     '
# Looks like you failed 41 tests of 41.
t/file-read.t ..... Dubious, test returned 41 (wstat 10496, 0x2900)
Failed 41/41 subtests 
t/pod-coverage.t .. skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ........... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
t/portfs.t ........ skipped: Test::Portability::Files required for testing filenames portability

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00-load.t     (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/file-read.t   (Wstat: 10496 Tests: 41 Failed: 41)
  Failed tests:  1-41
  Non-zero exit status: 41
Files=6, Tests=42,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.13 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/6 test programs. 42/42 subtests failed.
  SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (File::Slurp); additionally test harness failed
  ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz                : make_test NO one dependency not OK (File::Slurp); additionally test harness failed





cpan[2]> install File::Slurp
Running install for module 'File::Slurp'
Running make for U/UR/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/File-Slurp-9999.19-MKvwuC
  Has already been made
Running make test
  Has already been tested successfully
Running make install
  Already done
```

Answer (score 0):

`Can't locate File/Slurp.pm`

You have to install this (and other possible) dependencies.

You can do the below to tell CPAN to install all dependencies automatically.

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]>  o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan[2]>  o conf commit
exit
```

and then do

```
$ cpan File::Read
```

Or you can use [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5019/bin/cpanm).

```
$ cpanm File::Read
```

Comment: again the same issue..!

Comment: seems File:Read fails.  --> Working on File::Read
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SA/SAPER/File-Read-0.0801.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring File-Read-0.0801 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: File::Slurp
--> Working on File::Slurp
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/U/UR/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring File-Slurp-9999.19 ... OK
Building and testing File-Slurp-9999.19 ... OK
Successfully installed File-Slurp-9999.19
Building and testing File-Read-0.0801 ... FAIL
! Installing File::Read failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
1 distribution installed

Comment: Can you post the content of `build.log`?

Comment: its too long for characters to post here

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670968/cannot-locate-perl-module-even-if-cpanm-claims-it-is-up-to-date